# Компаратор для set

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-faq, set

Подскажите пожалуйста как написать свой компаратор для `set`.
Это будет использоваться в целях спортивного программирования.
Так что желательно попроще и поменьше кода.

Comment: Так ведь смотря для какой цели... Не существует единого универсального компаратора на все случаи жизни, и даже на случай спортивного программирования :)

Comment: для начала открываем исходники `stl` и смотрим туда

Comment: я имею ввиду, мне нужен пример. Как написать компоратор. Потому что я даже синтаксиса не знаю для этого дела.

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2620862/4928642

Answer (score 9):

Творчески перерабатывая пример @Qwertiy :)

```
int main()
{
    auto cmp = [](int a, int b) { return a > b; };
    set <int, decltype(cmp)> s(cmp);

    s.insert(2);
    s.insert(20);
    s.insert(12);
    s.insert(-7);

    for (int x : s)
        cout << x << ' ';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Прикольно! Не ожидал увидеть decltype для лямбды)))

Answer (score 7):

Берем предикат

```
bool compare(X const& lhs, X const& rhs) {
  return lhs < rhs;
}
```

и делаем из него класс:

```
#include <type_traits>
using Compare = std::integral_constant<decltype(&compare), &compare>;
```

Теперь его можно использовать как компаратор:

```
std::set<X, Compare> set;
```

Comment: Не знал об использовании `std::integral_constant` в таком контексте

Comment: Следует написать, где это тестировалось и если есть ограничения по компиляторам, то перечислить

Comment: [Восхищенно] перепроизнеси!... :)

Answer (score 4):

http://ideone.com/T2saIg

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

struct cmp
{
    bool operator() (const int &a, const int &b)
    {
        // returns true if a should go before b
        return a > b;
    }
};

int main()
{
    set <int, cmp> s;

    s.insert(2);
    s.insert(20);
    s.insert(12);
    s.insert(-7);

    for (int x : s)
        cout << x << ' ';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Abyx, вроде логично... Но ведь скомпилировалось?